# Issue with Hibernate Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three Domain classes

```
1.Question
2.Test
3.Category
```

I have following relation with these domains

```
1.Category has many test and test belong to a category
2.Category has many questions and question belongs to a category.
3.Test has many questions and question can belong to many tests.
```

I have written the following criteria, but this is not giving me output i want. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

```
Session session = getSession();
        List<String> tests = getCategoryTestIds(categoryId);
        List<Question> questions;

        questions =  session.createCriteria(Question.class)
                     .createAlias("tests", "test")
                     .add(Restrictions.and(
                             Restrictions.eq("category", new Category(categoryId)),
                             Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("test.id", tests))))
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
                    .list();
        }
```

I am getting questions as an empty list. I have checked in db for results. ideally  this should have given me a list of 10 question objects.

The above criteria is doing

Select All questions that belong to a Category  and does not belong to any Test.

Hibernate Query is following

```
select this_.id as id1_3_3_, this_.answer as answer2_3_3_, this_.category_id as categor11_3_3_, this_.explanation as explanat3_3_3_, this_.level as level4_3_3_, this_.option_a as option5_3_3_, this_.option_b as option6_3_3_, this_.option_c as option7_3_3_, this_.option_d as option8_3_3_, this_.question as question9_3_3_, this_.set_id as set10_3_3_, category3_.id as id1_0_0_, category3_.name as name2_0_0_, tests4_.question_id as question1_3_, test1_.id as test2_6_, test1_.id as id1_5_1_, test1_.category_id as category3_5_1_, test1_.name as name2_5_1_, category6_.id as id1_0_2_, category6_.name as name2_0_2_ from question this_ left outer join category category3_ on this_.category_id=category3_.id inner join test_question tests4_ on this_.id=tests4_.question_id inner join test test1_ on tests4_.test_id=test1_.id left outer join category category6_ on test1_.category_id=category6_.id where (this_.category_id=? and not (test1_.id in (?, ?))) order by this_.id asc limit ?
```

I have tried this query and got the following hibernate sql query

```
questions =  session.createCriteria(Question.class)
                     .createAlias("tests", "test")
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("category.id", categoryId))
                     .add(Restrictions.isNull("tests"))
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
                    .list();



  question this_ 

    left outer join category category3_ on this_.category_id=category3_.id

    inner join test_question tests4_ on this_.id=tests4_.question_id 

    inner join test test1_ on tests4_.test_id=test1_.id 

    left outer join category category6_ on test1_.category_id=category6_.id 

    where this_.category_id=? and this_.id is null 

    order by this_.id asc limit ?
```

The error is near `where this_.category_id=? and this_.id is null` here it is checking the id of question instead of tests

Comment: what sql query string did hibernate generate

Comment: Is it necessary to include the "not in" clause, or would be it be sufficient to just check if `test` is null?  It seems like this check would only be necessary if a question could be assigned to a test not in its category.

Comment: if i have to do this, what should my criteria look like ?  I am still not able to get this right

Comment: @MarkPeters can you help me, i have edited the question to include null query